# Phoenix.HTML: Creating form elements for belongs_to relationships

Tags: phoenix-framework

Given the schemas below

```
schema "contact" do
  field :name, :string
  field :phone, :string
  belongs_to :address, Db.Address
end

schema "address" do
  field :street, :string
  field :city, :string
  field :state, :string
  field :zip, :string

  has_one :contact, Db.Contact
end
```

Using Pheonix.HTML I’d like to populate the details of both contact and the address in a form at the same time, then use a transaction on the backend to first insert the address, and assign the new ID to the contact record before inserting it. I’ve got the Ecto part figured out, it is just the Phoenix.HTML side that I can't seem to get working.

Here is an excerpt of the non-working html.eex code.

```
<%= form_for @changeset, contact_path(@conn, :do_create_contact), fn cnt -> %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <%= text_input cnt, :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <%= text_input cnt, :phone, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Address</label>
    <%= inputs_for cnt, :address, fn addr -> %>
      <div>
        <small>Street</small>
        <%= textarea addr, :street, class: "form-control" %>            
        <small>City</small>
        <%= text_input addr, :city, class: "form-control" %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <small>State</small>
            <%= text_input addr, :state, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <small>Zip</small>
            <%= text_input addr, :zip, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am met with the the error `could not generate inputs for :address` Is it simply not possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add in future posts the full error message.
I have tested your code snippets and get the same error:
`(ArgumentError) could not generate inputs for :address from MyApp.Contact. Check the field exists and it is one of embeds_* or has_*`

Probleme here is you create the association in the wrong way.
Switch your `belongs_to` and `has_one`. The base model should hold the `has_*` field.

Change you schemas to:

```
schema "contact" do
  field :name, :string
  field :phone, :string

  has_one :address, Db.Address
end

schema "address" do
  field :street, :string
  field :city, :string
  field :state, :string
  field :zip, :string

  belongs_to :contact, Db.Contact
end
```

See [Ecto.Schema hexdocs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_one/3) for more details. Do **not forget** to change your migrations too!

Comment: This is the answer, thank you. There is no way to do what I want using a belongs_to relationship. This does create a situation where `address` would have multiple `belongs_to` entries if we came up with other data types that needed addresses, but I guess that is just how it has to be in this case.